# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified Gridview rowupdating

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I am trying to update a gridview with a stored procedure and i keep getting the error. I am using ms sql 2014 Time(7) field. I've tried all the "fixes" that are found online about having the same number of parameters in the stored proc as in the sqldatasource update parameters and other fixes that don't seem to work here. I'm wondering if there is something to do with the time(7) field?

Stored Proc

```
@BlockId int,
@AllDay bit,
@AssigerId int,
@EndTime time(7),
@StartTime time(7)

As
Begin
    Update Blocks 
    Set 
        Allday = @AllDay, 
        AssigerId = @AssignerId, 
        EndTime = @EndTime, 
        StartTime = @StartTime 
    Where BlockId = @BlockId
```

ASP

```
SqlDataSource
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssignConnectionString %>" deletecommand="deleteBlock" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="updateBlock" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">                   
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="BlockId"   Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AssignerId"   Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AllDay"   Type="Boolean" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="EndTime"   Type="Datetime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="StartTime"   Type="DateTime" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

VBCode

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Assignerddl"), DropDownList)
    Dim ckbx As DropDownList = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("AllDayck"), DropDownList)
    Dim editstartddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("editStartddl"), DropDownList)
    Dim editendddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("editEndddl"), DropDownList)

Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("assignConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    cn.Open()
    Dim updCmd As New SqlCommand("updateBlock", cn)
    updCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@BlockId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text
    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@AllDay", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ckbx.SelectedValue.ToString()
    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@AssignerId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString()
    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@EndTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = editendddl.SelectedValue.ToString()
    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = editstartddl.SelectedValue.ToString()


    SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
    updCmd.Parameters.Clear()
    bindBlocks()
End Sub


Gridview:

<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" Width="620px" CssClass="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCanceling" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" GridLines="None" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="BlockId" EmptyDataText="No Blocks For This Day"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />    
            <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="BlockId" DataField="BlockId" ReadOnly="true" visible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AllDay" DataField="AllDay" ReadOnly="true" visible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="StartTime" DataField="StartTime" ReadOnly="true" visible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EndTime" DataField="EndTime" ReadOnly="true" visible="false" />

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="25px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="25px" />
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                            <hr style="width:100%; margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                            <hr style="width:100%; margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;" />     
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefereeId") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>                         
                            <asp:Label ID="Label66" Font-Size="small" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("BlockId")%>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this block?');" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active Blocks"  >               
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:label id="Label1" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("BlockDate") %>'></asp:label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField  >
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            Start Time: <asp:dropdownlist ID="editStartddl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="StartTime2" DataValueField="StartTime2"
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StartTime2")%>'>                                    
                            </asp:dropdownlist><br />
                            End Time: <asp:dropdownlist ID="editEndddl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="EndTime2" DataValueField="EndTime2"
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EndTime2")%>'>                                    
                            </asp:dropdownlist>
                        </EditItemTemplate>               
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:label id="Label1rt" runat="server" Text='<%# "Block Start:  " + DisplayAs12HourTime(Eval("StartTime")) %>' visible='<%# IIf(Eval("AllDay") = "True", "False", "True") %>'></asp:label><br />
                            <asp:label id="Label32" runat="server" Text='<%# "Block End:  " + DisplayAs12HourTime(Eval("EndTime")) %>' visible='<%# IIf(Eval("AllDay") = "True", "False", "True") %>'></asp:label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full or Partial"  >
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropdownList ID="AllDayck" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AllDay") %>' runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="False">Part Day Block</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="True">Full Day Block</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropdownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>                
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:label id="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# IIf(Eval("AllDay") = "True", "Full Day Block", "Partial Day Block")%>'></asp:label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group"  >  
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:dropdownlist ID="Assignerddl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="AssignerId"
                                SelectedValue="<%# Bind('AssignerId') %>">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Block For All Groups</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:dropdownlist>
                        </EditItemTemplate>             
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:label id="Label111" runat="server" text='<%# IIf(Eval("AssignerId") = "0", "All Groups", Eval("CompanyName")) %>'></asp:label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>  

                </Columns>


            </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Your stored procedure has these parameters defined as `Time(7)`, your ASP has them as `DateTime` and your vb is putting a `ToString()` into them. That may be the problem.

Comment: Interesting, I did notice that, but the ASP does not offer Time as a parameter.. maybe that is a problem

Answer (score 0):

I changed bind to eval on the grid view and it worked without the error. Go figure…